# Trouble iterating through radio button values in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, google-apps-script

Working on a fairly straight-forward project for an employer. I need a survey form that when submitted will dump the answers into a spreadsheet. I am working from Google Apps Script on a standalone app. Project management decided against Google Forms.

What I'm having a problem with is retrieving radio button values. There are a multitude of radio button questions, and I need to be able to iterate through them to get their values.

The UI is done through GAS's UiApp service:

```
function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  // set up the form
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
  form.add(flow);
  app.add(form);

  // create the radio button groups (they are all Likert scales). 
  // I've written a function that creates a single group (see below)
  for (var i=0; i<24; i++){
    likertScale(i, flow);
  };

  flow.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit')

  return app;
}
```

My likertScale() function used to create the radio button group:

```
function likertScale(name, flow) {
  // the 'name' argument allows me to pass in the var i from the 
  // for loop above to give each radio button group a unique name
  // the 'flow' argument allows me to pass in the var flow that  
  // I created when setting up the form

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  // create the N/A option, assign the group's name, give the button a label 
  // and a value
  flow.add(app.createRadioButton('item'+name, 'N/A').setFormValue('NA'));
  for (var j=1; j<6; j++) {
    // create the 5-point Likert scale; assign the group's name to each button,
    // use j to give each a label and a value
    flow.add(app.createRadioButton('item'+name,j).setFormValue(j);
  }

  return app;
}
```

To test the premise of retrieving the values, I'm adding labels whose text contains the values to the app. The relevant parts of the function:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  for (var i=0; i<24; i++){
    var radio = 'item'+i; 
      // I've previously set the name of each radio button group 
      // as 'item#', where # is a number 0-23. 
    app.add(app.createLabel().setText('You selected ' + e.parameter.radio));
      // The idea is that each iteration recreates the name of a radio
      // button, then uses that name to inform e.parameter.radio 
  };

  return app;
}
```

What's really confusing for me is while the above code spits out 'You selected undefined' 24 times, the below code totally works:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel().setText('You selected ' + e.parameter.item0

  return app;
}
```

It seems that as long as I don't try any looping and I hand-code the whole thing, everything is fine.

Any insight on this?

Comment: Anyone trying to reproduce this will need to write a UI, guessing at what you have in it. You could help things along by providing all the (minimal) code that's required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't reference the variable "radio" that way, it will be interpreted as a property named "radio" try:

```
app.add(app.createLabel().setText('You selected ' + e.parameter[radio]));
```

See details on ways to access object properties here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties